# LiveData unit testing error when using postValue in init block

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to write a unit test for a view model using live data.

**LoginViewModel.kt**

```
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val context: Context
): ViewModel() {
    val username = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val password = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val isLoginButtonEnabled = MediatorLiveData<Boolean>().apply {
        fun combineLatest(): Boolean {
            return !(username.value.isNullOrEmpty() || password.value.isNullOrEmpty())
        }
        addSource(username) { this.value = combineLatest() }
        addSource(password) { this.value = combineLatest() }
    }

    init {
        username.postValue("test")
        password.postValue("test")
    }
}
```

**LoginViewModelTest.kt**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class LoginViewModelTest {
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val instantTaskExecutorRole = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private val context = mock(Context::class.java)
    private val loginViewModel = LoginViewModel(context)

    @Test
    fun loginButtonDisabledOnEmptyUsername() {
        val observer = mock<Observer<Boolean>>()
        loginViewModel.isLoginButtonEnabled.observeForever(observer)
        loginViewModel.username.postValue("")

        verify(observer).onChanged(false)
    }
}
```

My unit test throws the following exception at the line `username.postValue("test")`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
```

The `InstantTaskExecutorRule` should provide an execution context when using live data, however it doesn't work when initializing live data in the `init`-block. When omitting the `init`-block it works as desired, but i need the possibility to initialize live data variables.

Is there any way to make the live data initialization work when unit testing view models?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to unit test my `ViewModel` that was using `LiveData` using mentioned rula - `InstantTaskExecutorRule`. But in my case the rule val declaration was a bit different:

```
@Suppress("unused")
@get:Rule
val instantTaskExecutorRule: InstantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

Edit:

```
@Before
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun prepare() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
}
```

Edit2:

For some weird reason I cannot reproduce this :)
Also, I think that the problem could be because of the way you're initializing your ViewModel -

```
private val loginViewModel = LoginViewModel(context)
```

I assume that it initializes too early, thus it's init block gets called too early too. Maybe it's reasonable to create it in the `@Before` method ? Like:

```
private lateinit var viewModel: LoginViewModel

@Before
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun prepare() {
    loginViewModel = LoginViewModel(context)
}
```

Comment: I tried this out and got the same result: it works in general but not when using `postValue` in the init block.

Comment: @ngu, I think in order to make the rule work, you need to use `initMocks` method. See edit in answer.

Comment: `initMocks` is necessary to initialize mock objects annotated with mockito annotation like `@Mock`. Instead of annotation based initialization i used the `mock` method. I tried to use `initMocks` nevertheless and got the same result as before.

Comment: @ngu, I've updated my answer. I cannot reproduce your exception though. It's weird :)

Comment: Thanks, creating the view model in the prepare method did the trick!

Answer (score 10):

I was seeing a similar issue when setting a `LiveData` value during the `ViewModel`'s `init`. Demigod's solution pointed me in the right direction, but I wanted to explain a bit about what was going on and why in the lifecycle of the testing process.

When you have a `ViewModel` that sets the `LiveData` during `init`, it will be run as soon as the view model is initialized. When you initialize the view model in your unit test using `val viewModel = MyViewModel()`, that view model is instantiated at the same time as the test class is initialized. The problem there is any rules you may have are initialized at the same time, but are not actually *run* until after the class is completely initialized, so your `ViewModel.init()` is happening before the rules actually take effect. This means your live data isn't working on an instant executor, any Rx observables aren't being run on replaced schedulers, etc. So ultimately there are two ways of solving for this:

1. Define the view model as a `lateinit var` and initialize the view model as a in the `@Before` method of your test, which runs after rules are applied, or
2. Define the view model as a `val viewModel by lazy { MyViewModel() }`, which won't be run until you actually start calling it in your tests.

I prefer option 2 because it also allows me to set up any test-case-specific preconditions before my view model is ever initialized, and I don't have to do repetitive initialization code (which could be quite verbose) inside every test that requires it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and the answer provided by Demigod was not solving it. I finally found out where the devil was hiding so I share it here : my init block was set before the liveData initialization, which works fine when running the app, but not when running tests !

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

//    init {       // <-- Do not put the init block before the liveData
//        _myLiveData.postValue("First")
//    }

    private val _myLiveData: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
    val myLiveData: LiveData<String>
        get() = _myLiveData

    init {
        _myLiveData.postValue("First")
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide any code snippet to solve this issue?

Comment: Thank you @Uguzon you solved my issue after hours of searching...