# Observe StateFlow emission in ViewModel initialization

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow

I have a view model that takes in an initial `ViewState` object and has a publicly accessible `state` variable which can be collected.

```
class MyViewModel<ViewState>(initialState: ViewState) : ViewModel() {
    val state: StateFlow<ViewState> = MutableStateFlow(initialState)
    val errorFlow: SharedFlow<String> = MutableSharedFlow()

    init {
        performNetworkCall()
    }

    private fun performNetworkCall() = viewModelScope.launch {
        Network.makeCall(
            "/someEndpoint",
            onSuccess = {
                (state as MutableStateFlow).tryEmit(<some new state>)
            },
            onError = {
                (errorFlow as MutableSharedFlow).tryEmit("network failure")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

When observing this state from a fragment, I can see the initial state (loading for example) and I collect the change when the network call completes successfully (for example, to a loaded state.)

However, I am at a loss as to how to observe this emission from my `ViewModelUnitTest`.
I use kotlin turbine to test emissions for my state and shared flows, but I can only observe emissions that occur after I call `viewModel.state.test` or `viewModel.errorFlow.test`.

Since I cannot reference `viewModel.state` or `viewModel.errorFlow` prior to initialization of the ViewModel, how can I write a test to validate that my initialization logic performs correctly and emits the expected result based on the mocked behavior of `Network.makeCall` - whether it be a new emission of `state` or an `errorFlow` emission?

Answer (score 1):

Since your network class doesn't have any reference in the view model, it isn't possible to mock/fake `Network` class' behavior. So, create a reference for `Network`. To capture what's going on in the `init` block, you can lazy initialize your view model in the test class. It is described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61106564/13310043) as the second way. Roughly, your classes look similar to:

```
class MyViewModel<ViewState>(
    initialState: ViewState,
    network: Network
) : ViewModel() {
    val state: StateFlow<ViewState> = MutableStateFlow(initialState)
    val errorFlow: SharedFlow<String> = MutableSharedFlow()

    init {
        performNetworkCall()
    }

    private fun performNetworkCall() = viewModelScope.launch {
        network.makeCall(
            "/someEndpoint",
            onSuccess = {
                (state as MutableStateFlow).tryEmit(<some new state>)
            },
            onError = {
                (errorFlow as MutableSharedFlow).tryEmit("network failure")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

---

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MyViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    var coroutinesTestRule = CoroutinesTestRule()

    val viewModel by lazy { MyViewModel(/*pass arguments*/) }
}
```

`CoroutineTestRule` can be found in [here](https://github.com/android/trackr/blob/main/app-compose/src/test/java/com/example/android/trackr/compose/CoroutineTestRule.kt).